# Android Studio Error - Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image]

This is my build.gradle (Module:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doctor.ciao"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.devlight.pulseview:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'

}
```

I am getting two errors:

1. Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error
2. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

   > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error

I have already added `"android.enableAapt2=false"` to gradle.properties file but still the error persists. Please help me with this issue. Thank you

Comment: Open Gradle Console (bottom right) and find the entire error description.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found out the exact issue and fixed it.

Comment: Awesome! You can update your question and post an answer to it, so others can find it helpful.

Comment: Some of the images in my drawable folder were renamed automatically to "imagename.9.png". So it was showing an error as - 9 patch image error. By renaming the images to "imagename.png", the issue was solved.

Comment: @EugenPechanec. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had an invalid png file - I had a .jpg file that was accidentally renamed with the .png extension

To find the offending image file I ran this command in my app directory:

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -I {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'
```

Renaming the image file to a .jpg extension solved the problem and I could build again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. i am follow @Anubhav Sarangi 's comment bellow:

> Some of the images in my drawable folder were renamed automatically to
>   "imagename.9.png". So it was showing an error as - 9 patch image
>   error. By renaming the images to "imagename.png", the issue was
>   solved.

i check the images in my drawable folder, and i found there has an image that was not 9-patch image but named imagename.9.png, and i rename it to imagename.png, the problem solved.

there has a premise, need add "android.enableAapt2=false" to gradle.properties

thanks again @Anubhav Sarangi and @Eugen Pechanec

[this is my error tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udMCn.png)
[in this image, the title_bar.9.png is not 9-patch image, so i rename it to title_bar.png, and add android.enableAapt2=false to gradle.properties and click "Sync Now" and the problem solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dw1o.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after using the Android 3 and SDK 25.

Changing the SDK version from 25 to 27 helped.

The below is my build.gradle. I could recreate this by changing the SDK version from 27 to 25.

Hope this helps.

`compileSdkVersion 27`

`targetSdkVersion 27`

STACK TRACE

```
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.   at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
 org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to execute aapt  at
 com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:513)
    at
 com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:248)
    at
 com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
 org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)  at
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more     Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file
 processing failed, see logs for details        at
 com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.waitForAll(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:121)
        at
 com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:141)
        at
 com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:115)
        at
 com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:293)
        ... 48 more Caused by:
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
 aapt   at
 com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    at
 com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:491)
    ... 49 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
 com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
 check logs for details     at
 com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at
 com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at
 com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at
 com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:792)
    ... 50 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
 com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
 check logs for details     at
 com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at
 com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at
 com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at
 com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:177)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more Caused by:
 com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
 check logs for details     at
 com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
    at
 com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
    at
 com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at
 com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
```

Comment: I tried to help you with formatting a little bit. If you ok with this edition, you can remove your previous answer.